# Recurring payment for Paypal Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal

i am having a problem with the new Paypal Android SDK (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/).

I can not find a way to implement recurring payments (like the subscription button for web based) in the Pay by Paypal payment option in the Paypal Android SDK. Is this even possible with the Paypal Android SDK?

I have spent many days trying to figure out this, but have come to a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They PayPal Android SDK does not currently support recurring payments. For recurring payments, you can either use the [Mobile Payments Library for Android](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/) or [Mobile Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout/) for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

As JatinB already mentioned, the new Android mobile payments SDK PayPal released doesn't support recurring payments. Neither does PayPal's old native Android library which used to be called MPL.

Depending on your application requirements and which country its targeted towards you have few options to choose from:

- If application is targeted towards US market - [Stripe Android library](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) will allow you to tokenize credit card details and store them on the back end server for recurring payments. [Braintree Android library](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/android) also allows to save credit card details by using their Venmo Touch framework. In both cases you will have to get your hands dirty and do some development on the backend server side to implement recurring payment functionality (as this is down to your server to initiate recurring charges).
- If mobile application is targeted towards customers outside the US the choice of native libraries working across multiple countries is limited. Best option in that case would be to currently use already mentioned PayPal's Express Checkout product which is web checkout but has mobile optimized UX for mobile redirects (auto detects browsers user agent). You could embed this checkout flow into Android webview to avoid redirects to external web browser from your native app. And keep sending emails to guys in PayPal, Stripe and Braintree do they release mobile payment libraries countries outside US :)

Comment: thanks for the replies. I am sticking with the Android SDK, but i have handled the recurring payment functionality(i alert the user of the expired item and he has the choice to renew it or not) by developing a PHP script which will be run as a cron job on the server once a day and the script will check in our database when an item has expired and do what it has to do.

Comment: You are right, its always better handle these things on back end side. Its just a nice feature if library lets you setup this to be done silently