# Paypal recurring payment in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

Using Paypal iOS SDK, i can perform single payment. 
but i need recurring payment after some specific cycle. In which auto maniacally payments will get deducted from users Paypal account.

Please help me out if anyone is having any idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Paypal REST web services for Recurring Payments.

Comment: Can you please share link about this ?  Or sample demo would be nice to get an idea 

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/,  mobile SDK don't support recurring payment currently. If you want to deduct money from buyer's account after buyer sign agreement, you can try to use future payment.
Similar case: [Recurring payment for Paypal Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345113/recurring-payment-for-paypal-android-sdk) for your reference.